# How to import a folder/file from public folder to src folder in react

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Trying to import image folder from public folder to src folder in react but i kept getting error messages in the terminal and my chrome

[[the vscode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktnsl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtyL0.png)

Comment: Please copy the important parts into the question as text, don't paste a screenshot and let the community decipher your screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is inside a `Image` folder. So the import should be

```
import Airbnb from '/Images/airbnb.png'
```

If it gives webpack import error you can do it like this way

```
<img src='/Images/airbnb.png'/>
```

Here `/Images/airbnb.png` gives a direct link to the image of the public folder.

Answer (score 2):

you need to import from the folder in which the file exists

```
import Airbnb from '../../public/Images/airbnb.png'
```